# How to find the launcher activity

Tags: android

I need to find out the Launcher activity in my own Application class and check whether if it was running . What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you right, you'd be able to find it in the manifest file of your application.

look for an activity that has an intent-filter tag that looks like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

that's your activity.